# Protecting several web servers with mod_security and Apache

Tags: linux, networking, security, apache-2.4, web-server

I have several web servers in my network and I want to protect them all with `mod_security`. Most of these web servers are Microsoft IIS and a few are Nginx.

I want to protect them all with only one WAF machine. I mean, I have to place the WAF machine in front of all web servers. The requests should first come to the WAF machine and then it decides what to do with the request (redirecting them to the appropriate web server based on the destination address). All of these must be transparent to the clients and they should not be aware that the web server is behind a WAF.

The WAF is a Linux machine running Apache web server with `mod_security` 2.9.

What's the best way to do it? Should I use `mod_proxy`? or `mod_rewrite`? or just simple `Redirect`s? Should I configure the WAF as a forward proxy? or as a reverse proxy?

I got really confused. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sitting in front of the other web servers, it would be a reverse proxy. Probably Nginx would be a better option for your WAF.

Comment: Take a look at:

https://www.darknet.org.uk/2015/11/modsecurity-open-source-web-application-firewall/

Comment: Why would Nginx be the better option? It’s integration with ModSecurity is weaker.